# Sencha touch 2 reference to html for an event

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have some html in my panel:

```
styleHtmlContent: true,
scrollable: true,

items: {
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'titlebar',
    title: 'List'
        },
    html: [
        "<div style='border-radius: 4px;' class='abutton' id='abuttonbyid'>",
        "Text</div>"
    ].join("")
```

And in my controller

```
config: {
    refs: {
        abutton: '.abutton',
        abuttonbyid:'#abuttonbyid'
    },

    control: {
        abutton: {
            tap: 'onButtonTap'
        },
        abuttonbyid : {
            tap: 'onButtonTap'
        }
    },
},

onButtonTap: function() {
  console.log("Tapped");
}
```

I want it so when the div button is tapped, I get `Tapped` in my js console/web inspector.
I did both with a class and an element with an id because I would like to attach the event listener to many div buttons, instead of one. Many div buttons, one event.

I am required to use the html buttons instead of the Sencha buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add a button to your titlebar?

```
items: {
  docked: 'top',
  xtype: 'titlebar',
  title: 'List',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'button',
      text: 'Tap Me',
      handler: function() { console.log("button tap"); }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Since you say you have to use html (which isn't preferred), then you could add a custom listener delegated to your DOM node:

```
items: {
  docked: 'top',
  xtype: 'titlebar',
  title: 'List',
  html: [
    "<div style='border-radius: 4px;' class='abutton' id='abuttonbyid'>",
    "Text</div>"
  ].join(""),

  // The new "listeners" code...
  listeners: {
    tap: {
      fn: function(event, el){ console.log("tapped!"); },
      element: 'element',
      delegate: '#abuttonbyid'
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, I would look at this documentation on [event delegation](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176239-HOWTO-Adding-Event-Listeners-to-Component-Elements).

Comment: I have too many items to use a button. The reason i'm using divs is the shear amount of them. I wanted to create a delegate to a controller but i cant seem to do this

Comment: Well, the Sencha folks suggest using components whenever possible, and the refs uses a `ComponentQuery` to find things, so your CSS syntax won't work. That said, you could use `Ext.DomQuery` get the DOM node and attach your own listener. I'll add a separate answer for you to look at.

Comment: Actually, found a better way to do it with listeners... try that.

Comment: I created a listener, and used 'controller' as the reference to pass it onto the controller and its working well!!

Comment: hi akshat, can give some example